# Access session user id from java in php code igneter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use my user id in my Java project. I get my user id through session in PHP and then access it in my Java project. But it shows nothing in my Java project.

I get my user id through api call in java and in PHP api function, used the following code:

```
$user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
```

Normally this returns my user id when i call this funcion through api.
But in java when it calls the api, than it returns null.

```
user id  =
```

But if i hardcode the user id in PHP like this:

```
$user_id = "3";
```

Then java can get the user id through api call.  But do not want to use any hard code value in PHP. Any suggestions please.

Comment: i have also used session_start method before this but it not works.

Comment: Maybe Java is calling without a user session?

Comment: [see this](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=access+php+session+in+java&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=uO9SVo7eJIrsuASiu5DwDw)